# Firing trigger on SQL Server views

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, triggers, insert

Is it possible to write a trigger for a view in (SQL Server 2012) that will fire whenever new data is inserted in the original table the view is based on?

I already wrote a trigger with instead of insert, but it doesn't fire when I insert to the original table, only fire when I insert into the view..!

If not, what is the best solution to do this?

Comment: what is the  need for that

Comment: @TheGameiswar I have two SQL Servers with linked server between them lets call the servers A & B
What I want is whenever a new row inserted in A.invoices, a trigger of view in B will do some work..

The problem is I don't want to make the B database available or seen by A server..

Comment: AFAIK you can put INSTEAD OF trigger on the views.

Comment: @gofr1 I already did, but it's not working whenever a new row is inserted into the base table.. it's only working if I actually insert into view

Comment: If you insert a row into one of the base tables - it's **immediately** "visible" in the view, since the view doesn't actually **store** any rows or anything - it just re-queries the underlying tables....so I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve here - and it's probably redundant and not necessary...

Comment: @marc_s as I replied to TheGameiswar, the base table for the view located in different database, different Server it's linked by Linked Server..
so I want to detect whenever a new record inserted in the other SQL Server, my SQL Server do some work and I thought I could do this using a view to the base table.

And I can't add a trigger on the other SQL Server because I don't want my databases be seen by the other server.

Comment: The next time you select from the view, that new data will be available **automatically** - no need to "do some work" ..... still not understanding what you're trying to accomplish, really. If you want to be notified of the remote server's table changing - you need a trigger **on that remote table** - not on a local view ....

Comment: @marc_s Because I have "on the local server" stored procedures that I want to execute using the inserted data on the "remote server"..

The linked server is added in the local server, I don't want to add a linked server in the remote server..